# How to open corrupted ZIP files?

Tags: windows, compression, zip, file-corruption

How can I open (or repair) corrupted ZIP files on Windows?

Is there a way to force 7-Zip to open them?

Comment: 7-zip won't do this, as they stated in their FAQ: http://www.7-zip.org/faq.html in question 5. It's probably a nice thing to do from a developer perspective but for users it's not really helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[**Zip Repair**](http://www.diskinternals.com/zip-repair) from [Disk internals](http://www.diskinternals.com/) looks like a good application to do what you are after. This seems to be the only free fully-featured application that I could find to do what you are after.

[image]

That said, depending on how corrupt the file is, you may not have that much success with getting all of the files out in their proper condition. You will probably not be able to get all your files out (if at all).

Answer (score 3):

[IZArc](http://www.izarc.org/) is also able to open/repair corrupt archives and it is freeware.

Comment: just tried Zip Repair above to open a corrupted, 800 MB zip file. Windows and 7-Zip couldn't do it.  Zip Repair looked like it was working but then failed and crashed on the 2 attempts.  iZArc extracted it all without a hiccup.  Nice!

Answer (score 0):

[**Best Unzip Program to open Broken and Corrupted Zip files**](http://mwolk.com/blog/best-unzip-program-to-open-broken-and-corrupted-zip-files/)  -- [**Yes**](http://www.7-zip.org/), [**7-zip**](https://superuser.com/questions/5886/compressing-with-rar-vs-zip/5918#5918)!

If 7-zip cannot get all the files, I'd try with `joshhunt`'s Zip Repair reference.
Please do tell if you get more data extracted from a broken archive compared to that extractable by 7-zip.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the nature and extent of the damage, WinRAR has done an excellent job in recovering files from damaged archives.  I can usually recover 90%+ of the files.

Answer (score 0):

It bears pointing out that the regular ZIP command in the Info-ZIP distribution has an `-F` option to attempt to repair broken archives.

http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-repair-damaged-zip-files-with-terminal--mac-49294 shows how to use it on a Mac, but Unix will be identical, and Windows fairly similar (if you have the WinZip command-line version; look for `wzzip.exe`).

Comment: For the record, neither this nor Zip Repair nor iZArc helped me solve my problem.