# "extra bytes at beginning or within zipfile," won't open file

Tags: linux, compression, zip, archiving

I have an 8.3 gig zip containing tons of telescope observation data, but I can't extract no matter what I try. I've tried Archive Manager, unzip, and tried this guy's fix: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=661956 using `zip -FFv` to repair the archive. I'm also going to try putting this on my Windows system and running it there, but if there is anyway I can extract this file sharing that would be most appreciated. I'm running CentOS at work and have Windows 7 Ult at home.

```
Archive:  /u1/user/Downloads/HLADATA-1133822740.zip
warning [/u1/user/Downloads/HLADATA-1133822740.zip]:  8590163968 extra bytes at beginning or within zipfile
  (attempting to process anyway)
file #1:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  8590163968
  (attempting to re-compensate)
replace HST_10241_a1_ACS_WFC_F658N/HST_10241_a1_ACS_WFC_F658N_drz.fits? [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename: A
  inflating: HST_10241_a1_ACS_WFC_F658N/HST_10241_a1_ACS_WFC_F658N_drz.fits  
  error:  invalid compressed data to inflate
 bad CRC cb522ad6  (should be 245028b6)
file #2:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  432123638
  (attempting to re-compensate)
file #2:  bad zipfile offset (EOF):  432123638
file #3:  bad zipfile offset (lseek):  9454403584
file #4:  bad zipfile offset (lseek):  9487163392
file #5:  bad zipfile offset (lseek):  10011582464
file #6:  bad zipfile offset (lseek):  10077962240
file #7:  bad zipfile offset (lseek):  10517315584
file #8:  bad zipfile offset (lseek):  11070496768
file #9:  bad zipfile offset (lseek):  11158077440
file #10:  bad zipfile offset (lseek):  11815370752
file #11:  bad zipfile offset (lseek):  12254732288
file #12:  bad zipfile offset (lseek):  12877021184
file #13:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  8614811671
file #14:  bad zipfile offset (lseek):  9054167040
file #15:  bad zipfile offset (lseek):  9711460352
file #16:  bad zipfile offset (lseek):  10385596416
file #17:  bad zipfile offset (lseek):  11007836160
file #18:  bad zipfile offset (lseek):  11630084096
file #19:  bad zipfile offset (lseek):  11696463872
file #20:  bad zipfile offset (lseek):  12220915712
file #21:  bad zipfile offset (lseek):  12660277248
```

Comment: Perhaps this users findings may help you out?

[Link][1]


  [1]: http://superuser.com/questions/30579/tool-to-open-corrupted-zip-files?rq=1

Comment: What are the first bytes of the corrupted file? (Also, is the file is publicly available anywhere is contains it also confidential data?).

Answer (score 7):

## Use rather `7z x`

The default `unzip %x` fails to extract any `.zip` files larger than 4GB.

Instead, use the command `7z x`

Be careful though, unlike `unzip %x` which creates a new directory, `7z x` will extract in the current directory. The option `-o` allows to specify an output directory.