# How to disable the Windows built-in zip functionality

Tags: windows, zip

Is there anyway to disable the built-in zip functionality without using other zip programs?

Comment: `alex` has also already answered the other question: http://superuser.com/questions/35503/how-to-restore-windows-default-zip-file-functionality

Comment: Not me :). There's a lot of **alex** here!

Comment: @this alex, Ah! did not notice that. Well, you all seem to be like minded `;-)`.

Comment: Apparently :))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [this](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/nt/xp/registry/rtips30.shtml) article. Here's a short summary:

> run the following command:
>   `regsvr32 /u %windir%\system32\zipfldr.dll`
>
> Want to re-enable the built in zip
>   capability, run the following command:
>   `regsvr32 %windir%\system32\zipfldr.dll`

Comment: +1, for people like me who install 7-zip on the first step, such information is unlearned. Thanks for these notes `:-)`.

Answer (score 10):

Alex's answer describes how to disable zip folder support in Windows XP. Here is how to disable it for Windows Vista and Windows 7 ([source](http://codesociety.com/2009/07/27/disable-zip-folders-in-windows-7-vista-xp/)).

**Windows Vista**

> 1. Open Registry Editor (go to Start Menu -> Run and type “**regedit**“).
> 2. Navigate to **HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID** and delete the following keys:
>      **{E88DCCE0-B7B3-11d1-A9F0-00AA0060FA31}** and
>      **{0CD7A5C0-9F37-11CE-AE65-08002B2E1262}**.
> 3. Restart Windows and enjoy a life free from zip folders!

**Windows 7**

> The process is similar to Vista in terms of deleting the same registry keys. However, due to additional protections built-in, you must first change ownership of the keys to your username, which must be an administrator account.
>
> 1. Open Registry Editor (go to Start Menu -> Run and type “**regedit**“).
> 2. Navigate to **HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID** and perform steps 3-7 for each of the two keys:
>      **{E88DCCE0-B7B3-11d1-A9F0-00AA0060FA31}** and
>      **{0CD7A5C0-9F37-11CE-AE65-08002B2E1262}**.
> 3. Right-click on the key and select “Permissions…”. Click “Advanced” and then the “Owner” tab.
> 4. Select your username from the list.
> 5. Check the box next to “Replace owner on subcontainers and objects”. Click “OK”.
> 6. In the “Security” tab, select your username and grant Full Control. (If your username is not there, click “Add…”, type your username, then click “Check Names” and “OK”.) Click “OK” to apply the permissions settings.
> 7. Delete the registry key.
> 8. Repeat the process for the second key.
> 9. Restart Windows and enjoy a life free from zip folders!

Comment: +1 It's good to have this information available for other versions of Windows as well

Comment: Apparently it's [even harder](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-disable-zip-folders-in-win10-1909/56b952d8-c6ba-452d-8e95-2446622d76e6) to disable zip folders in Win 10 than before.