# ZIP archives not opening in Explorer on some Windows 10 machines

Tags: windows, windows-10, zip

I am a sysadmin and manage approximately 40 or so end user systems. Recently I upgraded most systems to Windows 10. Everything is working except for that some machines cannot open ZIP archives using the native unzipping tool built into Windows. Double-clicking zips does not bring them up in Explorer and right-click >> Extract All >> Extract gives the error: "Windows cannot complete the extraction. The Compressed (zipped) folder is invalid."

Zips can still be opened using 7zip or The Extractor though.

This is happening on five machines I tested, but two other machines can open them fine.

- Only thing I've found online that is similar to my issue: http://www.tenforums.com/general-support/19428-zip-file-file-explorer.html
- The reg file in question is not corrupt on any of the machines I tested.
- I have confirmed that our anti-virus client is not blocking zips.
- Machines are all updated to the latest patches.

  It is an odd problem. I much appreciate any help or insight that can be given.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/iyb8kd1cudvq8ff/zip.txt?dl=0

Comment: If these machines are booted into Safe Mode does the behavior still happen?

Comment: They do, yes. @Ramhound

Comment: Did you check the key **HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{E88DCCE0-B7B3-11d1-A9F0-00AA0060FA31}**, and if **zipfolder.dll** is registered? See http://superuser.com/questions/37578/how-to-disable-the-windows-built-in-zip-functionality

Comment: Can you upload the file type report for .zip from one of the affected systems? You can use [FileTypeDiag](https://www.pretentiousname.com/miscsoft/#FileTypeDiag) for that. Regarding the Extract All I had the same issue, and reindexing search fixed it.

Comment: @w32sh https://www.dropbox.com/s/iyb8kd1cudvq8ff/zip.txt?dl=0

Comment: Right-click the ZIP, choose Properties, see if there's an UNBLOCK button on the General tab of the Properties dialog.  If so, click it, then try again.  MS is saving us from ourselves.  Again.

Comment: Tried unblocking with every zip I've tested. Does not fix the issue. @SteveRindsberg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GUID values are messed-up.
See if this REG file fixes the problem.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CompressedFolder\CLSID]
@="{E88DCCE0-B7B3-11d1-A9F0-00AA0060FA31}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.zip\CLSID]
@="{E88DCCE0-B7B3-11d1-A9F0-00AA0060FA31}"
```

The REG file needs to be run from admin account.

Those two were missing in your file association dump and I stopped at that point. If the REG fix doesn't help, let me know so that I can go through rest of the dump.

Note that the above should fix the file association (double-click action) but may not fix the "Extract All" error you're seeing. That's most likely a different issue than file type associations.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Unfortunately this did not fix the issue.

Comment: Checked if the setting has applied correctly? You can compare by regenerating a file association dump.

Comment: It applied correctly. The registry edits were applied.

Comment: Give this [REG fix](http://pastebin.com/1yaEcNvA) a try. It has the Windows 10 defaults. If that doesn't help, pls post a new zip association report.

Comment: That new reg file fixed the issue. Thanks for the help!