# How to restore the ZIP icon on a file?

Tags: windows, zip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to restore Windows default Zip file functionality?](https://superuser.com/questions/35503/how-to-restore-windows-default-zip-file-functionality)

I downloaded a game which was at first in a ZIP file.  I don't know how but now every time I click it, it opens in a DOS window instead of showing me the files that make it up.  It doesn't show the ZIP folder icon.  Instead it shows the DOS box icon.  I need it to return to the way it was before so that I can unzip it so I can play the game.

Answer (score 2):

If you're opening it under windows, tyr clicking with the right button and in Open With... select the program that you use for zip files.

If you're under linux it would be the same, but I can't remember if it's Open with... or it's called different.

Comment: (IF USING WINDOWS) And when you get the "Open With" dialog. Also "check" the checkbox saying "Always use selected program to open this kind of file". You can find this checkbox in bottom of the dialog. This will permanently fix your issues (or until you mess up again :) )

Answer (score 0):

From a command prompt or the Start->Run box, enter this command and press ENTER:

```
regsvr32 zipfldr.dll
```

Then, create a .reg file with the [following contents](http://www.dougknox.com/xp/fileassoc/zipfolder_fix.reg) and run it.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.zip]
@="CompressedFolder"
"Content Type"="application/x-zip-compressed"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.zip\CompressedFolder]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.zip\CompressedFolder\ShellNew]
"Data"=hex:50,4b,05,06,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.zip\OpenWithProgids]
"CompressedFolder"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.zip\PersistentHandler]
@="{098f2470-bae0-11cd-b579-08002b30bfeb}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CompressedFolder]
"EditFlags"=dword:00000000
"BrowserFlags"=dword:00000008
"AlwaysShowExt"=""
@="Compressed (zipped) Folder"
"FriendlyTypeName"=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,\
  00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,\
  32,00,5c,00,7a,00,69,00,70,00,66,00,6c,00,64,00,72,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,\
  00,2c,00,2d,00,31,00,30,00,31,00,39,00,35,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CompressedFolder\CLSID]
@="{E88DCCE0-B7B3-11d1-A9F0-00AA0060FA31}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CompressedFolder\DefaultIcon]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,7a,00,69,00,\
  70,00,66,00,6c,00,64,00,72,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CompressedFolder\Shell]
@=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CompressedFolder\Shell\find]
"SuppressionPolicy"=dword:00000080

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CompressedFolder\Shell\find\command]
@=hex(2):43,00,3a,00,5c,00,57,00,49,00,4e,00,44,00,4f,00,57,00,53,00,5c,00,45,\
  00,78,00,70,00,6c,00,6f,00,72,00,65,00,72,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CompressedFolder\Shell\find\ddeexec]
@="[FindFolder(\"%l\", %I)]"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CompressedFolder\Shell\find\ddeexec\application]
@="Folders"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CompressedFolder\Shell\find\ddeexec\topic]
@="AppProperties"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CompressedFolder\Shell\Open]
"BrowserFlags"=dword:00000010
"ExplorerFlags"=dword:00000012

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CompressedFolder\Shell\Open\Command]
@="rundll32.exe zipfldr.dll,RouteTheCall %L"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CompressedFolder\Shell\Open\ddeexec]
@="[ViewFolder(\"%l\", %I, %S)]"
"NoActivateHandler"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CompressedFolder\Shell\Open\ddeexec\application]
@="Folders"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CompressedFolder\Shell\Open\ddeexec\ifexec]
@="[]"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CompressedFolder\Shell\Open\ddeexec\topic]
@="AppProperties"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CompressedFolder\ShellEx]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CompressedFolder\ShellEx\ContextMenuHandlers]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CompressedFolder\ShellEx\ContextMenuHandlers\ICQMenu]
@="{f802f260-519b-11d1-bb5d-0060974c6013}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CompressedFolder\ShellEx\ContextMenuHandlers\{b8cdcb65-b1bf-4b42-9428-1dfdb7ee92af}]
@="Compressed (zipped) Folder Menu"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CompressedFolder\ShellEx\DropHandler]
@="{ed9d80b9-d157-457b-9192-0e7280313bf0}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CompressedFolder\ShellEx\StorageHandler]
@="{E88DCCE0-B7B3-11d1-A9F0-00AA0060FA31}"
```