# Windows 7 extract and compress zip has been compromised by NCH's Express Zip program. How to fix?

Tags: windows-7, compression, zip, extract

I installed NCH's Express Zip, and now I can no longer use Windows 7's way of extracting and compressing. I would like to get rid of the NCH program and get back the original functionality of windows 7, including being able to right click and compress a folder into a zip file or extract a zip file into a folder. Does anyone know how to do this? Is there a specific program name that Windows 7 uses to do this? If it's not still there, can I download it from somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

The basic functionality is part of Windows 7, has been there since Windows XP - in other words that should be the default handler.

Have you uninstalled NCH Express Zip via Control Panel / Programs And Features, or it's own uninstall menu option?

If you have done that and the default zip handlers still don't work, then you could try a decent piece of software like WinZip or WinRAR, or the suggestions here:

[How to restore Windows default Zip file functionality.](https://superuser.com/questions/35503/how-to-restore-windows-default-zip-file-functionality)

Comment: The command line didn't work because my command window did not recognize the command "cmd". But the right click, open with, did work, thank you so much!