# Shell zip with unattended password

Tags: shell, passwords, encryption, zip, winzip

I have a script that runs some automatic zip generation using shell zip. The request is to add automatic encryption with password. From what I understand, the option `-e` is the right one, but it asks for the password by prompt; instead I need to make this step automatically, giving the password as an option or as a file.

In other words, if I write:

```
zip -e
```

Then a prompt asking the password two times is presented. Instead I want to do something like:

```
zip -e:thisisapassword
```

and have a zip file protected with password: `thisisapassword`

Does anyone any hints how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most forms of zip encryption do not support encryption with a command line password. 
Here is one form based on [Igor Pavlov](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Igor_Pavlov_%28programmer%29)'s [7-zip](https://superuser.com/a/5918/263) called **[jZip](http://www.jzip.com/command_line.php)** that might work -- have not tried it myself.

> Option: -s[password]

Answer (score 0):

Actually (if your are concerned with security) I would vote *against* automatic encryption with a fixed password in some script;
instead I would encrypt to a public key that requires no password to encrypt, but only to decrypt.
[GnuPG](https://www.gnupg.org/) can do such a thing (see [Option `--encrypt`](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Operational-GPG-Commands.html#Operational-GPG-Commands)).

However you'll have to generate a PGP/GPG key pair first (the public key goes to public (i.e.: where your script runs), while the private ("secret") key should go where you decrypt the files).

There are a plenty of manuals, guides, and HOWTOs available, explaing the details.