# What is the difference between .rar and .zip?

Tags: zip, rar

To me it seems that these two file types works exact the same way. Why would people use .rar files (especially for illegal downloads) when .zip is so much more easier to handle? You don't need external software to open .zip files according to what I have experienced. Appreciate some kind of explanation.

Regards.

Comment: This has been answered, in detail, before: http://superuser.com/questions/5886/compressing-with-rar-vs-zip

Answer (score 1):

While you cannot beat the accessibility of ZIP (Windows, Mac OS X can handle ZIP files within Explorer/Finder), the compression ratio of RAR is much, much better.

Rather than paraphrase someone else's words, here's a link to StackExchange's own Jeff Atwood detailing RAR vs. ZIP: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/02/dont-use-zip-use-rar.html